# Fixed timestep with interpolation + Collision detection

Tags: collision-detection, game-physics, game-loop

I've been reading this article: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/, because I'm going to implement physics/forces in my game engine.
Continuous collision detection is already implemented in my engine to avoid missed collisions for very fast moving projectiles.

I have two options:

- Semi-fixed timestep.
- Fixed timestep + interpolation.

Can I use Semi-fixed timestep(see Glenn Fiedler's article) together with physics/forces? I wonder, because that technique is based on variable delta time and fixed delta time, i.e.

```
while(frameTime > 0.0)
{
    deltaTime = min(frameTime, 1.0 / 60.0);
    //Physics + Collision here...
    frameTime -= deltaTime;
}
```

Fixed timestep seems to be the best option for stable physics, but the interpolation step(for smoother visuals, avoid temporal aliasing/jittery movement) destroys everything related to collision detection. The interpolation step will introduce some delay(up to one update tick) for the visuals, and that will result in non-sync between the actual collision detection behind the scenes and what you can see on your screen.

How can I sync the interpolated physics states for smoother visuals and collision detection with Fixed timestep?

Is it possible to use Semi-fixed timestep for physics/forces? How stable/unstable is this technique?

Comment: Have you tried the interpolation with collisions? You say there would be some jitter, but my guess would be that it was unnoticeable. I have no basis for this statement, however.

Comment: Jittering is very noticeable in my engine. My current solution: Sub-Stepping, works really well! Read the Technical Details here: https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Physics/Substepping/ It is very easy to code this.